# ISAPI_ReWrite redirect when there is a space in url

Tags: .htaccess, isapi-rewrite

I have a URL which contains white space which I am trying to redirect to another URL but some how the URL is not matched

The mapping file looks like

```
tours/cycle%20tour.htm cycle-tours.html
```

I have tried many way like

```
"tours/cycle%20tour.htm" cycle-tours.html
"tours/cycle tour.htm" cycle-tours.html
 tours/cycle\ tour.htm" cycle-tours.html
 tours/cycle\stour.htm" cycle-tours.html
```

but no chance. Can any one pls help me

Comment: `tours/cycle\ tour.htm` is correct. So the question is why that does not match. you will have to add information to the question for us to help: 1. the actual `.htaccess` style file you currently use, 2. the _precise_ request coming in, 3. the location where you placed that `.htaccess` style file and 4. you may have to turn on "rewrite logging" to be able to see what is actually going on inside your rewrite engine.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to encode spaces in the test string back. Use something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteMap map_txt txt:text_map.txt
RewriteMap map_escape int:escape

RewriteCond ${map_txt:${map_escape:$1}|NOT_FOUND} (.*)
RewriteCond %1 !NOT_FOUND 
RewriteRule (.+) %1 [R]
```